# Convolution of $l^2$ functions is not an $l^2$ function.

Tags: summation, convolution

Consider $$l^2(\mathbb{Z})= \left\{f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}: \ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |f(n)|^2 < \infty\right\}$$

and define the convolution of two functions $f,g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$(f*g)(x):= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n) g(x-n), \quad x \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I'm looking for two functions $f,g \in l^ 2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $f*g \notin l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ but couldn't find any examples. Is there some intuition that can guide me to a correct example? I tried with harmonic series but the calculations always get messy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your space be $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$? Otherwise, you need a square in the sum. Also note that $f \ast g \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$, if $f, g \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the typo. I can indeed see that the last claim you make is true, which follows after a straightforward calculation.

Comment: You can find a concrete counterexample in this article, but it also needs a little bit of Fourier transform: https://shann.idv.tw/articles/ell2.ps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f$ supported on $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with $f(n) = n^\alpha$ for $n > 0$, where $\alpha$ is a fixed constant which we will choose appropriately. Note that if $\alpha < 0$, the term $f(k)f(n-k) = (k(n-k))^\alpha$ is minimized at $k = n/2$, hence the bound
$$(f * f)(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k) f(n-k) \geq (n-1) (n/2)^{2\alpha} \geq (n/2)^{2\alpha + 1}$$
holds for $n \geq 2$. (In fact you can prove the stronger result that if $f$ and $g$ are supported on $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with $f(n) \asymp n^\alpha$ and $g(n) \asymp n^\beta$, then $(f * g)(n) \asymp n^{\alpha + \beta + 1}$ whenever $\alpha, \beta > -1$).

But $f$ is in $\ell^2$ so long as $\alpha < -\frac{1}{2}$, and by the above we see that $f * f$ is not in $\ell^2$ when $2\alpha + 1 \geq -\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $\alpha \geq -\frac{3}{4}$. Then setting $\alpha = -\frac{2}{3}$, $f$ is in $\ell^2$, but $f * f$ is not.

Comment: Looks promising! I will look at it in detail!

Answer (score 0):

If that was true, then applying Fourier transform you would see that the pointwise product of $L^2$ functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is also $L^2$.

Comment: I am not sure about this example, but maybe functions of the form $f(t)=t^\alpha$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$ is $L^2$ for some $\alpha$ bu $t^{2\alpha}=f(t)^2$ is not.

Comment: I rather want an explicit example as I'm not familiar with Fourier transforms. Also, I'm interested in $l^2$, not $L_2$. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: The idea is that the Fourier transform of a $\ell^2$ function is a $L^2$ function. So taking the inverse fourier transform of a function that is $L^2$ but its square is not would be an example.

Comment: Kindly provide an explicit example! I don't know about Fourier transforms